# retrieve this json array values

Tags: javascript, json

```
o = {
    "photos": {
        "page": 1,
        "pages": 46,
        "perpage": 5,
        "total": "230",
        "photo": [{
            "id": "6643924777",
            "owner": "34653895@N08",
            "secret": "3b7c2f6469",
            "server": "7153",
            "farm": 8,
            "title": "Huevos rellenos de bonito del norte Serrats",
            "ispublic": 1,
            "isfriend": 0,
            "isfamily": 0},
        {
            "id": "6371789575",
            "owner": "53643555@N08",
            "secret": "dda25093e0",
            "server": "6105",
            "farm": 7,
            "title": "ALBÓNDIGAS DE CARNE",
            "ispublic": 1,
            "isfriend": 0,
            "isfamily": 0},
        {
            "id": "6200723807",
            "owner": "17738873@N00",
            "secret": "bf4fc5c84f",
            "server": "6159",
            "farm": 7,
            "title": "albóndigas en salsa",
            "ispublic": 1,
            "isfriend": 0,
            "isfamily": 0},
        {
            "id": "6201239628",
            "owner": "17738873@N00",
            "secret": "def72cc124",
            "server": "6128",
            "farm": 7,
            "title": "albóndigas en salsa",
            "ispublic": 1,
            "isfriend": 0,
            "isfamily": 0},
        {
            "id": "6171324677",
            "owner": "34653895@N08",
            "secret": "9f7a7489f5",
            "server": "6161",
            "farm": 7,
            "title": "Pastel de patata con bonito del norte de Conservas Serrats y bechamel",
            "ispublic": 1,
            "isfriend": 0,
            "isfamily": 0}]}

}
```

This is the flickr API json result of a query
I am tring like this

```
for (var key in o) {
    for (var key1 in o[key]) {
        var current = o[key][key1].id;
        console.log(key1);    //returns the pages information
        console.log(current); //returns null
    }    
}
```

Basically i need to construct images with this format

```
<img src="http://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < o.photos.photo.length; i++) {
    var photo = o.photos.photo[i];

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    var src = 'http://farm' + photo.farm + '.staticflickr.com/' + 
               photo.server + '/' + photo.id + '_' + photo.secret + '.jpg';
    img.setAttribute('src', src);

    // TODO: do something with the img DOM element we just created
}
```

and here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X9AFh/).

Answer (score 2):

Try

[jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) - Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.

or

[jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) - Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object